# Which join will Spark choose when all the selection criteria are not met?

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

We know that in Spark have three types of joins -- Broadcast Join， Shuffle Join and Sort-Merge Join：

- when small table join big table，use Broadcast Join；
- when small table big than BroadcastJoinThreshold，use Shuffle Join；
- when big table join，and join key can sort，use Sort-Merge Join；

What happens in a case where there is a join of two big tables and the join key can't be sorted? Which join type Spark will choose?

Comment: pls elaborate on join key cannot sort...the code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark 3.0 and above supports these types of joins:

- Broadcast hash join (BHJ)
- Shuffle hash join
- Shuffle sort merge join (SMJ)
- Broadcast nested loop join (BNLJ)
- Cartesian product join

Their selection is best outlined in the source code for [`SparkStrategies.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L106):

```
  /**
   * Select the proper physical plan for join based on join strategy hints, the availability of
   * equi-join keys and the sizes of joining relations. Below are the existing join strategies,
   * their characteristics and their limitations.
   *
   * - Broadcast hash join (BHJ):
   *     Only supported for equi-joins, while the join keys do not need to be sortable.
   *     Supported for all join types except full outer joins.
   *     BHJ usually performs faster than the other join algorithms when the broadcast side is
   *     small. However, broadcasting tables is a network-intensive operation and it could cause
   *     OOM or perform badly in some cases, especially when the build/broadcast side is big.
   *
   * - Shuffle hash join:
   *     Only supported for equi-joins, while the join keys do not need to be sortable.
   *     Supported for all join types except full outer joins.
   *
   * - Shuffle sort merge join (SMJ):
   *     Only supported for equi-joins and the join keys have to be sortable.
   *     Supported for all join types.
   *
   * - Broadcast nested loop join (BNLJ):
   *     Supports both equi-joins and non-equi-joins.
   *     Supports all the join types, but the implementation is optimized for:
   *       1) broadcasting the left side in a right outer join;
   *       2) broadcasting the right side in a left outer, left semi, left anti or existence join;
   *       3) broadcasting either side in an inner-like join.
   *     For other cases, we need to scan the data multiple times, which can be rather slow.
   *
   * - Shuffle-and-replicate nested loop join (a.k.a. cartesian product join):
   *     Supports both equi-joins and non-equi-joins.
   *     Supports only inner like joins.
   */
object JoinSelection extends Strategy with PredicateHelper { ...
```

As stated, the outcome of applying the selection depends not only on the size of the tables and sortability of the keys, but also on a join type (`INNER`, `LEFT/RIGHT`, `FULL`) and join key conditions (equi- vs non-equi/theta). Overall, seems like in your situation you'll be looking at either Shuffle Hash or Broadcast Nested Loop.